# Passing html id to and mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an game news website and I have a problem in the code. I need to the client to press a news button, choosing one of many news, and the button id, which is the news id, need to go to a controller method, then the controller will take that news and show in another view.

Here is the view code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">News List</div>
<table>
    @foreach (var a in Model)
    {
        <tr>@Html.ActionLink("Read More", "Post", "Home", new { id = @a.Id }, null)</tr>
    }
</table>
```

And here is the controller method, wich is in the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Post(string id)
    {
        Post post =  this.post.ChosePost(id);
        return View(post);
    }
```

This should call a view with the html view on the previous link but it's not, and I do change the mapRoute but isn't working at all, the value don't go to controller.

Comment: Have you tried just a regular link? <a href="/Home/Post/@a.Id">Read More</a>

Comment: Long shot, but try changing `Post` method to `Posts`. Remember to change it the `ActionLink` too.

Comment: Does you link look like you'd expect in html?

Comment: I've tried regular link and it didn't work, it will try to go to a /Home/Post/"newsId" wich doesn't exist, the news page is the /Home/Post, and the news page shows the news from the model, and switching the name might work, i'll try this out.

Comment: Try `public ActionResult News(long id)`